# How to run background service in ios forever for syncing of data

Tags: c#, ios, background, xamarin.ios, xamarin

Hi I am developing an App which has a requirement to do syncing operation (data submission and retrieval) on web server.

User can submit forms offline (ie. storing data to local db on device). And whenever network is available, background service should submit those data to web server.

The detail requirement of background service is like:

- Background service will first check whether network is available or not
- if network is available, it will collect the data store in Local db (SQLite)
  on device
- It submit the data to server
- ask server to have any new    data, and if available, get that data
  and update the local database    on device.

I am quite new to iOS and xamarin/monotouch, and would like to know how to achieve this?

I know about various background modes in iOS, such as background fetch, nsurlsession, background transfer etc.

I have try to implement Background Fetch which i think is suitable for my situation. but it runs on it's own time.

Also would like to know that if user has killed my application, then also background fetch will invoke and still run my application ?

the code is something like this in my appdelegate -> PerformFetch method:

```
if(networkService.IsNetworkAvailable())
{
   if(this.syncDataService.DownloadNewDataFromServer())
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Data downloaded successfully from server..");
   }
   if(this.syncDataService.UploadDataToServer())
   {
       Console.WriteLine("Data submitted successfully to server...");
   }
   completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NewData);
}
else
{
   completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.NoData);
}
```

**Update:** Finally I have implemented it like this way (hope it can be helpful for someone) :

```
public class LocationUpdatedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    private CLLocation location;

    public LocationUpdatedEventArgs(CLLocation location)
    {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public CLLocation Location
    {
        get { return this.location; }
    }
}

public class LocationManager
    {
        private static DateTime lastServiceRun;

        private CLLocationManager locMgr;

        public LocationManager()
        {
            this.locMgr = new CLLocationManager();
            this.LocationUpdated += this.PrintLocation;
            this.locMgr.Failed += (object sender, NSErrorEventArgs e) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("didFailWithError " + e.Error);
                Console.WriteLine("didFailWithError coe " + e.Error.Code);
            };
        }


        public event EventHandler<LocationUpdatedEventArgs> LocationUpdated = delegate { };


        public static TimeSpan TimeDiff { get; set; }


        public CLLocationManager LocMgr
        {
            get
            {
                return this.locMgr;
            }
        }


        public void StartLocationUpdates()
        {

            if (CLLocationManager.LocationServicesEnabled)
            {
                // sets the accuracy that we want in meters
                this.LocMgr.DesiredAccuracy = 1;

                //// Location updates are handled differently pre-iOS 6. If we want to support older versions of iOS,
                //// we want to do perform this check and let our LocationManager know how to handle location updates.

                if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(6, 0))
                {
                    this.LocMgr.LocationsUpdated += (object sender, CLLocationsUpdatedEventArgs e) =>
                    {
                        //// fire our custom Location Updated event
                        this.LocationUpdated(this, new LocationUpdatedEventArgs(e.Locations[e.Locations.Length - 1]));
                    };
                }
                else
                {
                    //// this won't be called on iOS 6 (deprecated). We will get a warning here when we build.
                    this.LocMgr.UpdatedLocation += (object sender, CLLocationUpdatedEventArgs e) =>
                    {
                        this.LocationUpdated(this, new LocationUpdatedEventArgs(e.NewLocation));
                    };
                }

                //// Start our location updates
                this.LocMgr.StartUpdatingLocation();

                lastServiceRun = DateTime.Now;

                // Get some output from our manager in case of failure
                this.LocMgr.Failed += (object sender, NSErrorEventArgs e) =>
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Error);
                };
            }
            else
            {
                //// Let the user know that they need to enable LocationServices
                Console.WriteLine("Location services not enabled, please enable this in your Settings");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The stop updating location.
        /// </summary>
        public void StopUpdatingLocation()
        {
            this.locMgr.StopUpdatingLocation();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// The print location. (This will keep going in the background)
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"> The sender. </param>
        /// <param name="e"> Location updated event argument </param>
        public void PrintLocation(object sender, LocationUpdatedEventArgs e)
        {
            CLLocation location = e.Location;

            Console.WriteLine("Longitude: " + location.Coordinate.Longitude);
            Console.WriteLine("Latitude: " + location.Coordinate.Latitude);

            var diff = DateTime.Now - lastServiceRun;
            TimeDiff = diff;
            if (TimeDiff.Minutes == 2)
            {
        // RunInBackground() is my method which call the service to upload/download data from server
                if (this.RunInBackground())
                {
                    lastServiceRun = DateTime.Now;
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: How you implemented this? I am having exact task(using Xamarin) to sync phone with server for every 5 minutes, I too tried background fetch, but its not calling sync for every 5 minutes. I read your below comment that you have used LocationService, can you able to share your code or some links about how you done this?

Comment: @Subha I have updated my question with the code which I used to call the location service. Let me know if you have any query.

Comment: Thanks for you response. I asked [this](http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/105216#Comment_105216) question in forum and I was suggested to use remote push notification. We have decided to use push notification, as our app is nothing to do with location service. I just wanna know am I able to use location service just to run some function in background without updating any location?

Comment: @Subha - Yeh you can use location service. Since, apple does not provide any way for backgrouding service, so using Location service is a way to run things in background. and it automatically calls. But if you have a larger task to do in background, then I suspect that it may not allow you to it executing. Also location service can be harmful for battery drainage. as it continue polling locations so battery can be drain fast. So keeping all this thing in mind you can determine the approach.

Comment: Is this stil valid and the best way to go? Could you show us the RunInBackground() method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The timer never works in background, and you cannot add another thread in this method. `DidEnterBackground` is used to complete pending tasks. This will usually last for approximately 30secs - 1 minute.

You can add a loop or add a long running task in this method.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand that timer will never work in background but i have a requirement like running background service to sync data (upload and download) from server. I tried background fetch, but its not reliable. So can you highlight some points/suggestion on how to achieve such functionality in iOS?

Comment: I had a similar requirement, what I did is: Added a timer that invokes a method in background (but this works only when the App is active but it does not hampers the normal flow of the project). Then on background I call it once. Later when my app again comes to the foreground, it again continues the timer. This is a workaround as I tried many methods, I also tried adding notifications on entering background and foreground but can't make repeated calls to the method in background

Comment: How about putting some call in location service? is it fine if we add some custom logic when location changed event occurs?

Comment: As far as what I have read about, you can do it. Apps that have location services, audio, video, news can run in background forever. iOS doesn't kill that app. But yes if you are gonna submit it to the Appstore, you better be using the services. Try and hope it works, and once done dont forget to post your answer, meanwhile I too would try.

Comment: Okay, I have implemented the same and it's working fine. I put a condition to sync data to every X minutes in location service. it's working fine and app doesn't kill or crashed. but still i need to check whether Apple store will approve it or not?

Comment: Thanks for your help and support.

Comment: I am not very sure with the approval process in this case, since none of my apps till now needed to use such services that needs to keep my app alive.

Comment: Please someone clarify me on this, How to use location service without any location update just for sync purpose alone? I too want to achieve similar thing???

Answer (score 3):

I believe the solution to your problem is to register your task as a long running task.

Considering that you are using Xamarin, there is also a very good explanation on background tasks using Xamarin [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/backgrounding/introduction-to-backgrounding-in-ios), which would probably be more relevant to what you want to do.

Also, have a look at [App States and Multitasking](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html) for an explanation on what is happening when an application goes to the background: " After returning from the applicationDidEnterBackground: method, most apps move to the suspended state shortly afterward. Apps that request specific background tasks (such as playing music) or that request a little extra execution time from the system may continue to run for a while longer."

In general looking at the apple developer site is a good thing since 100% of iOS APIs are in Xamarin

Answer (score 2):

In your app delegate on FinishedLaunching you create timer, that will invoke you code in the time interval that you will set

```
    public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        ...
        Timer timer = new Timer(5000); //5000 milisecs - 5 secs
        timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
        timer.Start();
        ...
    }

    private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        //your code here
    }
```

Also if user will kill your app it means that no code even background fetch will not invoke any more

Comment: It means, our app should be running in order to work in background task. is there any way to handle such situation.. also, putting timer will also drain the battery. isn't it? are there any chances to reject the app from app store?

Comment: No, there is no way to handle such situation, it's not android where you can create some service, if app killed then there is no way to run any code. It will drain battery only when you code will be invoked but not all the time

Comment: Thx for your answer. But if i used above code then my app should run in foreground. while i want it to be run from background. so how to do that?

Comment: Sorry, didn't get, what exactly do you mean by "to be run from background"?

Comment: i mean My app needs to be on. if user opens another app, my app goes in background and the code never executed.

Comment: you should override DidEnterBackground method in you AppDelegate, and put the code that you want to run in background there.

Comment: I tried putting the same code there with the timer, but it will not executed. any ideas? i can put timer inside DidEnterBackground correct?

Comment: So it didn't execute after setted time interval? Then I think you are doing something wrong. And yes, correct.

Comment: i did: 'public override void DidEnterBackground(UIApplication application){}

Comment: the code that will be inside DidEnterBackground(UIApplication application){} will execute only when the app will enter in the background mode.

Comment: `public override void DidEnterBackground(UIApplication application)
    {
    base.DidEnterBackground(application);
    Console.WriteLine("Entering background");
    Timer timer=  new Timer(5000);
    timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
    timer.Start();
    }
    
    private void timer_Elapsed(object sender,ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
     RunInBackground();// this method have all the code to execute in background.
    }`

Comment: but my timer event is never fired when app is in background.

Answer (score 2):

A thought, for iOS. A way of doing it could be to create a background task scheduler, possibly based on LimitedConcurrencyLevelTaskScheduler (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee789351(v=vs.110).aspx), that will execute your IBackgroundTask jobs. These jobs could be persisted to a storage and will be performed sequentially. E.g. if you wanna download a lot of large files, you wanna do them one by one and show progress or render them in UI as they land on your device.
Then you enqueue any downloading task with this scheduler and you restart it when it's about to die:

```html
void StartBackgroundTask()
{
 BackgroundTaskId = UIApplication.SharedApplication.BeginBackgroundTask(() => {
  // Handle expiration: will happen before reaching 600 secs
  TaskScheduler.Stop();
  UIApplication.SharedApplication.EndBackgroundTask(BackgroundTaskId);

  // Start again
  StartBackgroundTask();
 });

 Task.Run(() => {
  TaskScheduler = new BackgroundTaskScheduler().Start();
 });
}
```