# Create iOS service to keep working in the background

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, background-service

I'm developing a GPS vehicle geolocation application.. if the user activates notifications in the app settings, so it must start checking the server every X minutes to verify if there are new vehicle alerts or not. For that I need a service that works when the app in the foreground and keep working even when the user put the app in the background to continue searching for notifications.

So I tried to do it like that (AppDelegate):

```
public override void DidEnterBackground(UIApplication application)
    {
        if (Preferences.Get(nameof(App.IsNotificationsServiceRunning), false))
        {
            nint taskID = UIApplication.SharedApplication.BeginBackgroundTask(() => { });
            new Task(() => {
                DoWork();
                UIApplication.SharedApplication.EndBackgroundTask(taskID);
            }).Start();
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
    }

//TIMER
public void DoWork()
    {

        var minutes = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(2);

        Device.StartTimer(minutes, () => {

            //check for notifications
            checkNotificationsFromServer();

            // Returning true means repeat this timer
            return true;
        });
    }

public void checkNotificationsFromServer(){
   //Some code here...
}
```

The problem with this code is.. First, the app will never check for notifications until it is placed in the background !
Second (it's a little weird) but this solution works on the iOS emulator but it doesn't work on a physical device (iphone 11) ! it means when the app is in the background the checkNotificationsFromServer() is never called !

Any suggestions plz ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run background service in ios forever for syncing of data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22756134/how-to-run-background-service-in-ios-forever-for-syncing-of-data)

Comment: My suggestion is to search before asking, because by now I have seen at least dozen exactly the same question. This way you are wasting both your time and time of other people.

Comment: @IvanIčin it's not exactly what I'm looking for, I'm trying to find a solution to start a task (when the app is in the foreground) and keep it working in the background too !

Comment: I don't see anything in that question that prevents answering with the solution that you try to find. Also to provide you some help with your use case, what you want is done with push notifications.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to achieve what you want.

1. There are [Background Modes (deprecated in iOS 13.0)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/scenes/preparing_your_ui_to_run_in_the_background/extending_your_app_s_background_execution_time)
2. There are [Background Tasks (iOS 13.0+)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks)
3. You could delegate the work to your backend and leverage classic Remote Notifications (or silent notifications for that matter)
4. You can artificially force system to keep the app running. Since you are developing an GPS app it is completely justifiable to keep reading users location. It should extend the app lifetime in background. But be aware, if you overuse this feature Apple will reject the app. But if you are using users location anyway, it should keep your app running.